# Why iterating over keyset is giving some incorrect output?

Tags: java, hashmap

```
public static int maxFrequencyNumber(int[] arr){ 
        /* Your class should be named Solution
         * Don't write main().
         * Don't read input, it is passed as function argument.
         * Return output and don't print it.
         * Taking input and printing output is handled automatically.
        */
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        for(int i : arr) {
            if(map.containsKey(i)) {
                map.put(i, map.get(i) + 1 );
            }else {
                map.put(i, 1);
            }
        }
        int maxFreq = 0;
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for(int i : map.keySet()){
            if( maxFreq < map.get(i) ) {
                maxFreq = map.get(i);
                max = i;
            }
        }
        return max;
    }
```

In the above code if i iterate over the array in the second for loop then all the output are correct but iterating over keyset gives some wrong outputs.
Why is that happening?

Comment: I don't see any "outputs". Not in your current code and not provided in your question. Can you clarify what you are seeing what we don't see? What output are you expecting, what output are you geting?

Comment: you need to change `for(int i : map.keySet())` to `for(Integer i : map.keySet())`

Comment: @sanjeevRm When I run it, it does not matter if that is `for (int i` or `for (Integer i`.  makes the same output.

Comment: @sanjeevRmThanks bro that gives all output correct but i still don't understand what the issue was. Can you please explain a bit like how this changes the output?

Comment: @Codered The output is the same whether it is `Integer` or `int`.  See the example I posted as an answer (because comments don't take code). If you had some issue with the code, you still haven't stated it. It seems that you fixed your own code, before your posted it.

Answer (score 0):

@Codered How is your code output "wrong"?  (Containing code and printlns inserted for inspection)

```
public class SandBox {

public static void main (String args[]) {
    int [] f = new int [] { 1, 9, 100, 123, 100, 9, 9, 7, 2 };
    System.out.println ("\nMost frequent number:  " + maxFrequencyNumber (f));
}

public static int maxFrequencyNumber (int [] arr) {
    HashMap <Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap <> ();
    for (int i : arr) {
        if (map.containsKey (i)) {
            map.put (i, map.get (i) + 1);
        } else {
            map.put (i, 1);
        }
    }
    int maxFreq = 0;
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int i : map.keySet ()) {
        System.out.println (i + ":  " + map.get (i));
        if (maxFreq < map.get (i)) {
            maxFreq = map.get (i);
            max = i;
        }
    }
    return max;
}

}
```

Output:

```
1:  1
2:  1
100:  2
7:  1
9:  3
123:  1

Most frequent number:  9
```